# Examples on Drum Sim Build for iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, touch

I'm trying to build a drum simulator in Xcode for an app for my brother in laws band. I'm having a little trouble doing this. What I'm wanting to do is use a picture of the drummer's drum set and use that as the drum you can play on the iPhone. I was thinking it could kind of be like an image map in HTML where the buttons would play a sound of the drum and everything else. If anyone has any ideas or how-tos on this it would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A very basic approach:

Use a [`UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with an image of the drumkit as background.

Create a transparent UIView in front of each drum. Attach a [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to each UIView. This gesture recognizer should call a different method for each view. Use [`AVAudioPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) to play the sound.

That's just a very basic app but not so bad. After you've done with that your next tasks could be:

- optimize performance. Sound should play in the moment you touch the display.
- multitouch
- use core motion to detect the strength of your tap and adjust the sound

Answer (score 0):

A UIImageView with some nice invisible buttons (UIButton's tintColor property as in `button.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];`) over the skins would be perfect.  Then, take a look at how to play some audio over here: http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2011/05/19/3831.aspx